# How Do I Disable "Bluetooth Headset and Handsfree Profiles" on Sony Vaio? So I Can Use Multiconnection Mode for LG HBS-700

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, sony-vaio

I have recently purchased a LG HBS-700 Bluetooth Stereo Headset. It comes with a multi-connection mode so that two devices can be connected to the headset at the same time.

However, both devices cannot simultaneously run Handset/Hands-free AND A2DP profiles or only one device will connect.

I want to link my cell phone (Droid 2) and my laptop (Sony Vaio model VPCEA36FM running on Windows 7) to the headset using the multi-connect option. Basically, I would like to listen to music/audio on my laptop while still being able to answer my phone...all through the headset.

**Is there a way to *temporarily disable* the Handset/Handsfree profile from my laptop?** I would prefer **not** to delete any profiles.

*[NOTE]* I am able to connect my cellphone and laptop to the LG HBS 700 headset separately.
Also, I have searched online, read my Vaio's manual, contacted Vaio technicians and have not found an answer. I am waiting to hear back from LG.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **disable the option from your phone**, not the computer, I had the same problem. but I enter on the Bluetooth settings from your phone and tell him that the headset is just connected to the phone audio not the media audio, thne connect the headphones to the phones, turned them off and on an voila, it works